# Macbook Air 1,1 power consumption

Tags: macbook-pro, power, battery

I have the original MBA, and I have extremely high power consumption - see the screenshot (screenshot got while TextEdit only was running)
[image]

Is is normal for original MBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is on the high site with 1400.

My MBA-13 consumes 1100 without TextEdit and 1200 with.

I do have Chrome and Friefox ect. running.

You might have some background stuff running, so check your Activity monitor and see who is using CPU.

Disable your network or wifi.

Comment: No, I have 95% CPU idle. I just runned my MBA and got 1880, but now I have 1331. Is there any methods to reduce this power consumption?

Comment: Just to compare, I have 98% idle, no programs running from user (other than system information), my power drain is (-) 1000 mAh. So that is the lowest my MBA can do with 100% screen. But i noticed you have new battery!

Comment: Yeah, just replaced it. But my MBA works only for 3 or 3.5 houts, and this is sad